# How to ship or export an sdl project made in codeblocks

Tags: c++11, sdl, codeblocks

The project uses external image files and codeblocks is configured to find the library and header files for SDL. How can I turn the project into a format so that it can be easily shipped ? I intend to create a single executable file or an installer which is portable . 
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've done that many times.

You just have to put the necessary DLLs (I use SDL 1.2, so `SDL.dll`, `SDL_image.dll`,`zlib.dll`, ...) where the executable is, which may be not so good with codeblocks/VC++ tree and the `Debug/bin` & `Release/bin` directories but would work with a `.bat` file which could run the executable.

OR

Consider that your development project is NOT the one the users will see.

Do you think that Microsoft guys code all `system32` commands in one single source directory?

So develop however you like and then create a deliver script to put everything in the root directory. Like that you don't have the constraints of delivered product while you are developping and reverse.

I recommend this approach.

Checkout [My bagman SDL remake](http://jotd.pagesperso-orange.fr/bagman/index.html) to see what I mean

When I create the archive for distribution, I use a custom script that I include here. This one has all the works, libmpeg for mp3 decompression, and all. If you unzip the [Bagman archive](http://jotd.pagesperso-orange.fr/bagman/bin/Bagman-win32-1.2.zip), it works right away on a windows PC.

Here's my directory tree

```
Bagman\bin
Bagman\exploit
Bagman\icons
Bagman\music
Bagman\obj
Bagman\resource
Bagman\sound
Bagman\src
Bagman\work
Bagman\bin\Debug
Bagman\bin\Debug256
Bagman\bin\Release
Bagman\exploit\mkf
Bagman\obj\Amiga
Bagman\obj\Debug
Bagman\obj\Debug256
Bagman\obj\NDS
Bagman\obj\NDSEMU
Bagman\obj\Release
Bagman\obj\Debug\src
Bagman\obj\Debug\src\characters
Bagman\obj\Debug\src\engine
Bagman\obj\Debug\src\gfx
Bagman\obj\Debug\src\screens
Bagman\obj\Debug\src\sys
Bagman\obj\Debug256\src
Bagman\obj\Debug256\src\characters
Bagman\obj\Debug256\src\engine
Bagman\obj\Debug256\src\gfx
Bagman\obj\Debug256\src\sys
Bagman\obj\NDS\src
Bagman\obj\NDS\src\characters
Bagman\obj\NDS\src\engine
Bagman\obj\NDS\src\gfx
Bagman\obj\NDS\src\sys
Bagman\obj\NDSEMU\src
Bagman\obj\NDSEMU\src\characters
Bagman\obj\NDSEMU\src\engine
Bagman\obj\NDSEMU\src\gfx
Bagman\obj\NDSEMU\src\sys
Bagman\obj\Release\src
Bagman\obj\Release\src\characters
Bagman\obj\Release\src\engine
Bagman\obj\Release\src\gfx
Bagman\obj\Release\src\sys
Bagman\resource\1x
Bagman\resource\maps
Bagman\resource\1x\images
Bagman\resource\1x\sprites
Bagman\src\characters
Bagman\src\engine
Bagman\src\gfx
Bagman\src\screens
Bagman\src\sys
```

Here's the python script that copies all necessary files in the user archive:

```
import sys,os,zipfile,re,shutil,glob
import find,which  # custom modules I created myself


MODULE_FILE = sys.modules[__name__].__file__
PROGRAM_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(MODULE_FILE))
ROOTDIR=os.path.realpath(os.path.join(PROGRAM_DIR,os.pardir))

PRODUCT_NAME="Bagman"

music=False
dev=False

version = "1.2"

print("making archive for version "+version)

os.chdir(ROOTDIR)
archname=PRODUCT_NAME+"-win32-"+version+".zip"

zfn = os.path.join(ROOTDIR,os.pardir,archname)
if os.path.exists(zfn):
    os.remove(zfn)

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zfn,mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

dll_list = ["SDL.dll","SDL_Mixer.dll"]+["smpeg.dll","libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll","libstdc++-6.dll","libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll"]  # MP3 playing needs the second part

items_list = ["bagman*.bat","*.cbp","*.dev","*.txt","COPYING","resource","exploit","sound","src"]

real_items_list = []
for i in items_list:
    real_items_list.extend(glob.glob(i))

for d in dll_list:
    print("processing '"+d+"'")
    dp = which.which(d)
    if len(dp)==0:
        raise Exception("%s not found in PATH" % d)
    zf.write(dp[0],arcname=PRODUCT_NAME+"/"+d)

for i in real_items_list:
    print("processing '"+i+"'")
    if os.path.isfile(i):
        zf.write(i,arcname=PRODUCT_NAME+"/"+i)
    else:
        fnd = find.Find()
        items = fnd.init(i)
        for f in items:
            if i == "resource" and os.path.basename(f) in ["settings","soundbank.bin"]:
                pass
            else:
                fi = f.replace(os.sep,"/")[2:]
                if os.path.isfile(fi):
                    if fi.endswith("~"):
                        pass
                    else:
                        zf.write(fi,arcname=PRODUCT_NAME+"/"+fi)
                else:
                    zfi = zipfile.ZipInfo(PRODUCT_NAME+"/"+fi+"/")
                    zf.writestr(zfi, '')

zfi = zipfile.ZipInfo(PRODUCT_NAME+"/bin/")
zf.writestr(zfi, '')
zfi = zipfile.ZipInfo(PRODUCT_NAME+"/bin/Release/")
zf.writestr(zfi, '')
zfi = zipfile.ZipInfo(PRODUCT_NAME+"/bin/Debug/")
zf.writestr(zfi, '')
zf.write("bin/Release/bagman.exe",arcname=PRODUCT_NAME+"/bin/Release/bagman.exe")

zf.close()
```

I know that there are existing python modules which will help you achieve such things (`distutils`). I did not use them because I wasn't aware of them.